# ASP.NET Treeview control and Client side javascript - Highlight selected tree view node

Tags: treeview, asp.net-2.0, selection, treenode

How to do following -
ASP.NET 2.0 TreeView and Selecting the Selected Node **using JavaScript**

I am trying this by reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ClientSideTreeView.aspx),but it does not find getTreeNode() property on asp.net 2.0 treeview control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Solution - for selecting single node (highlighting) ASP.NET 2.0 Treeview Control on Client Side

```
$("#TreeView1t5").addClass("TreeView1_5");
```

Where `#TreeView1t5` is id of `node` and `TreeView1_5` is `css class` for selection.

Enjoy..!